# How Format Angular Date in HTML page

Tags: angular

I try to format date in Angular HTML page and shows as :

```
    Apr 11, 2019 3:13 PM PST
```

I don't know how show PST?

This is my date Pipe:

```
 import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
 import * as moment from 'moment';

  @Pipe({
  name: 'utcDate'
  })

public transform(value: Date, format: string = 'M/D/YYYY'): string {
    return value ? moment.utc(value).format(format) : 'N/A';
 }
}
```

This is my code in HTML:

```
     {{ note.createdDate | utcDate : 'MMM d, YYYY HH:MM A'}}
```

and it is showing the date like:

```
 Apr 2, 2018 11:04 AM
```

How I can get PST at end?

Comment: What about using the pipe `t.createDate | date: ’long’` ?

Answer (score 0):

angular date pipe doesn't natively support timezone abbreviations in that format. they display as offsets, like `GMT-8`

but you'd use this format string to get close to your desired format:

```
"MMM d, y h:mm:ss a z"
```

if you want time zone abbreviations, you'll need to write your own pipe or find a library.

Comment: I am still getting this as Oct 4, 2019 08:10 AM without PST.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-m1sj5n?file=src/app/app.component.html I'm not sure what this `localDate` pipe you're using is... is it from some library?

Comment: I added my pipe and Edit my question with recent code changes.

Comment: you should consult the moment docs: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/ but it looks like they used to use the same `z` for timezone but it's been deprecated and you might need some plugin

Answer (score 0):

You use the [DatePipe](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe) provided by Angular.
The most simmilar built in format to what you want is `long`. It has also an additional comma after the year.

```
{{ text.createdDate | date:'long' }}
```

To get exactly what you want you can give specific format.

```
{{ text.createdDate | date:'MMMM d, y h:mm:ss a z' }}
```

Update as the other answer mentions the timezone from the  date pipe is not in the same format so to get he exact formatting you will need to create a custom pipe using a third party library. One that is very known is [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) that has a special [timezone library](https://momentjs.com/timezone/) for that.

Comment: angular native date pipe does not support timezone abbreviations. they display as offsets like `GMT-8`